# Web - my GraphQL request getting 403 error

Tags: python, web-scraping, graphql, anti-bot

I'm trying to scrap info from https://stockx.com/ using their API

It have been working previously but now I am getting 403 error, but the point is that my mate is also getting the same error from the script however he didnt use that script previously

I have copied my headers from developers console by getting info from https://stockx.com/air-jordan-1-low-se-craft-tech-grey

I am not sure if I changed something in script or I am getting blocked by cloudfare , do you have any ideas how I can bypass this problem using requests ? Maybe you have worked on the same issues.

Thnaks in advance

I have used the following request

Request URL:
https://stockx.com/api/p/e

Request:

{"query":"query GetMarketData($id: String!, $currencyCode: CurrencyCode, $countryCode: String!, $marketName: String) {\n  product(id: $id) {\n    id\n    urlKey\n    title\n    uuid\n    contentGroup\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n        highestBid\n        highestBidSize\n        lowestAsk\n        lowestAskSize\n      }\n      salesInformation {\n        lastSale\n        salesLast72Hours\n      }\n    }\n    variants {\n      id\n      market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n        bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n          highestBid\n          highestBidSize\n          lowestAsk\n          lowestAskSize\n        }\n        salesInformation {\n          lastSale\n          salesLast72Hours\n        }\n      }\n    }\n    ...BidButtonFragment\n    ...BidButtonContentFragment\n    ...BuySellFragment\n    ...BuySellContentFragment\n    ...XpressAskPDPFragment\n    ...LastSaleFragment\n  }\n}\n\nfragment BidButtonFragment on Product {\n  id\n  title\n  urlKey\n  sizeDescriptor\n  productCategory\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n      highestBid\n      highestBidSize\n      lowestAsk\n      lowestAskSize\n    }\n  }\n  media {\n    imageUrl\n  }\n  variants {\n    id\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n        highestBid\n        highestBidSize\n        lowestAsk\n        lowestAskSize\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment BidButtonContentFragment on Product {\n  id\n  urlKey\n  sizeDescriptor\n  productCategory\n  lockBuying\n  lockSelling\n  minimumBid(currencyCode: $currencyCode)\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n      highestBid\n      highestBidSize\n      lowestAsk\n      lowestAskSize\n      numberOfAsks\n    }\n  }\n  variants {\n    id\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n        highestBid\n        highestBidSize\n        lowestAsk\n        lowestAskSize\n        numberOfAsks\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment BuySellFragment on Product {\n  id\n  title\n  urlKey\n  sizeDescriptor\n  productCategory\n  lockBuying\n  lockSelling\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n      highestBid\n      highestBidSize\n      lowestAsk\n      lowestAskSize\n    }\n  }\n  media {\n    imageUrl\n  }\n  variants {\n    id\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n        highestBid\n        highestBidSize\n        lowestAsk\n        lowestAskSize\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment BuySellContentFragment on Product {\n  id\n  urlKey\n  sizeDescriptor\n  productCategory\n  lockBuying\n  lockSelling\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n      highestBid\n      highestBidSize\n      lowestAsk\n      lowestAskSize\n    }\n  }\n  variants {\n    id\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      bidAskData(country: $countryCode, market: $marketName) {\n        highestBid\n        highestBidSize\n        lowestAsk\n        lowestAskSize\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment XpressAskPDPFragment on Product {\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    state(country: $countryCode) {\n      numberOfCustodialAsks\n    }\n  }\n  variants {\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      state(country: $countryCode) {\n        numberOfCustodialAsks\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment LastSaleFragment on Product {\n  id\n  market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n    statistics(market: $marketName) {\n      ...LastSaleMarketStatistics\n    }\n  }\n  variants {\n    id\n    market(currencyCode: $currencyCode) {\n      statistics(market: $marketName) {\n        ...LastSaleMarketStatistics\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n\nfragment LastSaleMarketStatistics on MarketStatistics {\n  lastSale {\n    amount\n    changePercentage\n    changeValue\n    sameFees\n  }\n}","variables":{"id":"air-jordan-1-low-se-craft-tech-grey","currencyCode":"USD","countryCode":"US","marketName":"US"},"operationName":"GetMarketData"}

Comment: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask